# Finding strongly connected components of directed graph, kosaraju

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion, graph

Given a graph in `[[sourcevertex,targetvertex],...]` format with all the directed edges of the graph I am trying to optimize the code here because it still hasn't stopped running I don't know if it will take days or hours, although it is somewhat working for small input sets.  I think the masking/vertex renaming part of the code might be slowing things down, and possibly some inefficient use of various data types... any ideas on how I could make it more efficient?

It basically doesn't even get through the first DFS Loop (been waiting for a long time and wrote this up in the meantime).

```
import re
import numpy as np
from numpy import copy
from operator import itemgetter


#scc function, given an edge table, find all the SCC's and sort from largest to smallest
def scc(myInputList, mylistlength):
    global vertexStateTable
    global t
    global finishingTime
    global vertexStateTable2

    #put input list in numpy format
    directedGraph = np.array(myInputList)

    #define max source
    maxSource = directedGraph[:,0].max()

    #define max target
    maxTarget = directedGraph[:,1].max()

    #define max vertex
    maxVertex = directedGraph.max()

    #define a state table[]    [seen vertices set]
    vertexStateTable = set([])

    #define the finishing time counter
    t=0

    #define the finishing time dictionary
    finishingTime = {}

    #dfs loop
    for i in reversed(xrange(1, maxVertex+1)):
        #check if it's in the vertex state table for vertices already seen
        if i not in vertexStateTable:
            DFSFinish(directedGraph, i)

    print "Completed first round.  Finishing Times."

    #finishing time dictionary completed, now create equivalent 
    #create finished list in numpy format, replacing original list with state table finishing times from the first round
    finishedDirectedGraph = maskDirectedGraph(directedGraph, finishingTime)

    print "Masking Complete."

    #set vertexStateTable for second pass 
    vertexStateTable2 = set([])



    #initialize group counter
    sccSizes = np.array([])

    print "starting outer loop second round."
    #dfs loop
    for i in reversed(xrange(1,maxVertex + 1)):

        #check if it's in the vertex state table, already seen
        if i not in vertexStateTable2:
            #initialize time
            t=0 


            #DFSFinishingTimes(given list, max vertex, statetable)
            DFSSCCFinder(finishedDirectedGraph, i)



            #append groups, leader
            if sccSizes.size ==0:
                sccSizes=np.array([[i,t]])
            else:
                sccSizes = np.concatenate((sccSizes, [[i,t]]))

    print "Completed SCC second round."

#resort scc table by number of members
    sortedSCCTable = sorted(sccSizes, key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True)

    #return final scc Table
    return sortedSCCTable


#function to mask all the elements of the graph using key value pairs from dictionary
def maskDirectedGraph(myGraph, myDictionary):
    newGraph = copy(myGraph)
    for elem in newGraph:
        count0 = 0
        count1 = 0
        for k, v in myDictionary.iteritems():
            if count0+count1 == 2:
                break
            if elem[0]==k and count0==0:
                elem[0]=v
                count0+=1
            if elem[1]==k and count1==0:
                elem[1]=v
                count1+=1       
    return newGraph

#DFSFinishingTimes, given graph and starting vertex(list, vertex i ), perform a DFX loop, update the dictionary table of finishing times 
def DFSFinish(myDirectedGraph, myVertex):   
    #first initialize some variables
    global vertexStateTable
    global t
    global finishingTime



    #get usable edges
        #find all instances of myvertex in column 2, return pair
    wanted_set = set([myVertex])  # Much faster look up than with lists, for larger lists


    @np.vectorize
    def selected(elmt): return elmt in wanted_set  # Or: selected = wanted_set.__contains__

    outgoingConnectedEdges =  myDirectedGraph[selected(myDirectedGraph[:, 1])]


    if myVertex in vertexStateTable:
        return

    if outgoingConnectedEdges is None:
        if myDirectedGraph[selected(myDirectedGraph[:, 0])] is None:
            return

    #initialize unexploredOutgoingConnectedEdges
    unexploredOutgoingConnectedEdges = np.array([])
    #get unexplored directed edges.
        #loop through outgoing connected edges, keeping only those which are not on the list
    for edge in outgoingConnectedEdges:
        if edge[0] not in vertexStateTable:
            if unexploredOutgoingConnectedEdges.size == 0:
                unexploredOutgoingConnectedEdges=np.array([edge])
            else:
            unexploredOutgoingConnectedEdges = np.concatenate((unexploredOutgoingConnectedEdges, [edge]))


    #add current vertex to vertexStateTable as seen.
    if myVertex not in vertexStateTable:
        vertexStateTable.add(myVertex)


    #for each unexplored arc, recursively run the DFSFinish
    for unexplored in unexploredOutgoingConnectedEdges:
        DFSFinish(myDirectedGraph, unexplored[0])

    t = t+1

    finishingTime[myVertex] = t

#DFSSCCFinder, given graph with vertices renamed by finishing times, perform DFX loop, counting members instead of assigning finishingTimes
def DFSSCCFinder(myDirectedGraph, myVertex):    
    global vertexStateTable2 
    global t

    #get usable edges
        #find all instances of myvertex in column 1, return pair
    wanted_set = set([myVertex])  # Much faster look up than with lists, for larger lists


    @np.vectorize
    def selected(elmt): return elmt in wanted_set  # Or: selected = wanted_set.__contains__


    outgoingConnectedEdges =  myDirectedGraph[selected(myDirectedGraph[:, 0])]

    if myVertex in vertexStateTable2:
        return

    if outgoingConnectedEdges is None:
        if myDirectedGraph[selected(myDirectedGraph[:, 1])] is None:
            return

    #initialize unexploredOutgoingConnectedEdges
    unexploredOutgoingConnectedEdges = np.array([])
    #get unexplored directed edges.
        #loop through outgoing connected edges, keeping only those which are not on the list
    for edge in outgoingConnectedEdges:
        if edge[1] not in vertexStateTable2:
            if unexploredOutgoingConnectedEdges.size==0:
                unexploredOutgoingConnectedEdges = np.array([edge])
            else:
                unexploredOutgoingConnectedEdges = np.concatenate((unexploredOutgoingConnectedEdges, [edge]))


    #add current vertex to myStateTable as seen.
    if myVertex not in vertexStateTable2:
        vertexStateTable2.add(myVertex)


    #for each unexplored arc, recursively run the DFSFinish
    for unexplored in unexploredOutgoingConnectedEdges:
        DFSSCCFinder(myDirectedGraph, unexplored[1])

    #finished node, so increment finishing time counter
    t = t+1


#main procedure
while 1==1:
    masterInputList = []
    try:
        with open(raw_input("Text File: ")) as f:
            for line in f:
                masterInputList.append([int(x) for x in re.findall(r'\b\S+\b',line)])

        #define length of unsorted list: listLength
        masterListLength = len(masterInputList)
        print "List Length = "
        print masterListLength


        stronglyConnectedComponents = scc(masterInputList, masterListLength)

        #then print the sorted list
        print "Sorted List of Strongly Connected Component Groups(10):"
        iCount=0
        for line in stronglyConnectedComponents:
            print line
            iCount+=1
            if iCount>=10:
                break

    except IOError:
        print "File Not Found"
```

Comment: For intentionally infinite `while` loops, I recommend just using `while True:` as this is more common practice and seems more readable.

Answer (score 2):

First, main procedures of an executable Python script should **always** use this at the very bottom of the script to define the main entry point of the program:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main() # or whatever your main execution code is
```

See Guido van Rossum's well-known post about this topic: http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=4829

Second, your `while 1==1` statement will always be true, and the `break` statement you have inside the `for` loop only exits the `for` loop...that is, your script will **always** run forever the way you have it set up unless there is an error besides `IOError` in the `try` block. If there is an `IOError`, it will just `print "File Not Found"` and loop over the `while` statement again.

Comment: thanks a lot for looking at it.  Advice is noted.  I was actually more focused on the performance of this thing... running through my data set, after a closer look, with a large graph, like a million nodes and a few million edges, it basically takes days to complete the calculation due to inefficiency within the recursion...